# Why does using the and operator to compare 2 objects in an if statement throw an error when using 2 if statements does not

Tags: c++

I a method isTileEqual in my tile class, I am trying to compare the private variables shape and colour with another tile class. When I use the current line using the and operator Visual Studio Code gives me an error "expression must be a modifiable value"

when i nest the if statements as commented out below I receive no error.

```
bool Tile::isTileEqual(Tile tile) {
    Colour colour = tile.getColour();
    Shape shape = tile.getShape();

    if(this->shape == shape && this->colour = colour) {
        //if(this->colour == colour) {
            return true;
        //}
    }
    return false;
}
```

The expected result would be true if 2 tiles have identical properties. or false if they differ

Comment: Typo:  `this->colour = colour` --> `this->colour == colour`

Comment: Look carefully at your `if` statement. One comparison is not like the other.

Comment: @archhmod asking something trivial isn't wrong. You just did not put any effort into finding out the problem.

Comment: Nothing is 'thrown' here. Don't misuse standard terminology. This s a compilation error, and it is printed.

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got only one `=` on the one that uses `&&`.
With a single `=` it is an assignment, you want to do a comparison.

Should be:

```
if(this->shape == shape && this->colour == colour) {
```

I'd also suggest that you just return the value of the expression directly:

```
return this->shape == shape && this->colour == colour;
```

The `if (x) return true; else return false;` ... is considered ugly/bad practice.